# Factory with parameters in InversifyJS

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I'm using [InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) with TypeScript.

Let's say I have a class which has a mixture of injected and non-injected constructor parameters:

```
@injectable()
export class MyClass {
    constructor(
      foo: Foo, // This thing isn't injectable
      @inject(Bar) bar: Bar // This thing is
   ){
      ...
   }
}
```

I would like to inject a factory for this class into some other class and then invoke it with a value for the first parameter.

```
@injectable()
export class SomeOtherClass {
   constructor(
      @inject("Factory<MyClass>") myClassFactory: (foo: Foo) => MyClass
   ){
      const someFoo = new Foo();
      const myClass = myClassFactory(someFoo);
   }
}
```

My question: **is there some auto-magic in Inversify that will allow me to inject this factory?**

The best I've come up with so far is this:

```
bind<interfaces.Factory<MyClass>>("Factory<MyClass>").toFactory(context =>
    (foo: Foo) => 
        new MyClass(foo, context.kernel.get<Bar>(Bar))
);
```

But that means I'm explicitly `new()`-ing `MyClass` and every new injectable dependency of `MyClass` has to be added here too.

Is there a better way? Perhaps something based on parameter names like [Ninject Factory Extensions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of InversifyJS. I don't think there is a problem about using `new` inside the factory, remember that the job of the factory is to create a **new** instance.

It is true that calling `container.get<T>` multiple times inside a factory is [not a good thing](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

I can suggest breaking the initialization of `MyClass` into to phases:

The class instantiated by the factory:

```
@injectable()
export class MyClass {

    public c: C; // This thing isn't injectable
    public d: D; // This thing isn't injectable

    // PHASE 1: instantiation
    constructor(
      @inject(A) a: A // This thing is
      @inject(B) b: B // This thing is
   ){
      ...
   }

   // PHASE 2: initialization
   public init(c: C, d: D) {
      this.c = c;
      this.d = d;
   }

}
```

The class that uses the factory:

```
@injectable()
export class SomeOtherClass {
   constructor(
      @inject("Factory<MyClass>") myClassFactory: (c: C, d: D) => MyClass
   ){
      // you only use "new" with entities that are not injected by inversify
      const c = new C(); 
      const d = new D();
      const myClass = myClassFactory(c, d);
   }
}
```

And the factory:

```
bind<interfaces.Factory<MyClass>>("Factory<MyClass>").toFactory(context =>
    (c: C, d, D) => {

        // PHASE 1: instantiation
        let myClass = context.kernel.get<MyClass>("MyClass"); // a and b are injected

        // PHASE 2: initialization
        myClass.init(c, d); // c and d are initialized

        return myClass;

    }
);
```

I hope it helps and please share your ideas on the GitHub issues if you think you know a better way.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's definitely an improvement on having to `get()` every dependency of the class. That said, I may suggest another approach on GitHub.

Comment: @remo-h-jansen Isn't a two phase initialization an [anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) in itself? Every user needs to know, that init is a mandatory call, and that the dependencies are not available in the constructor. Wouldn't it be better to be able to tell inversify: "The first N argument I resolve myself, the next M dependencies are done by the container". The example factory is also very static. It would need one factory method for every concrete instance of an interface whenever the dependencies differ from the expected ones.